# Can't delete data from the last remaining node of a single linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I'm trying to delete all nodes of a singly-linked list in C with the following code.

```
void free_all(struct cd *head){                                                 
    struct cd *tmp;                                                                                                                                            
    tmp = head->next;                                                           
    while(tmp != NULL){                                                         
        head->next = tmp->next;                                                 
        free(tmp);                                                              
        tmp = head->next;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    free(head->next);                                                           
    free(head);                                                                 
    head=NULL;                                                                  
}
```

But if I print all elements of the linked list after that to check if the list is empty or not, the "head" element is always printed. So it looks like the head element isn't being deleted properly. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'head' is an function argument, with local scope. So although you set it to NULL at the end of the function, this will have no effect as the function just returns right after, moving that variable out of scope.

Whatever variable was passed in, will still point at the head of the list (though this memory has been freed, it likely still contains plausible data).

The head *has* been freed. It just doesn't necessarily look that way, because you've kept a pointer to the memory where it used to live.

To fix it, simply null the pointer out *after* calling this function to free the list.

```
free_all(actual_head);
actual_head = NULL;
```

You could pass in a pointer to a pointer, in order to NULL the pointer within the function, but that seems overly complex for this situation.

Comment: Why would the variable still point at the head of the list? And how can I fix it.

Comment: I've expanded on my answer a little to try to answer that, but basically because you haven't actually changed the variable, you've just changed a local copy of it. Once the function returns, that local copy is gone, and your original still remains.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean and it works. But as I know head is a pointer so it is "call by reference" which means that only a reference is given to the function and there is no local copy or am I wrong with this?

Comment: You're passing by pointer. The head structure has not been copied, but when you pass the pointer to it into the function, that pointer is copied into a local variable. If you want to reference the pointer itself, you need another level of indirection.